# Stubbing node.js lambda function that converts a csv to json

Tags: json, node.js, csv, lambda

I have an AWS lambda function that converts CSVs into zipped json files. I was told to write unit tests by making sample input csv files and then checking the json output without making actual calls to AWS. I'm pretty new to Node.js, and am wondering what would be the best way to go about this? I'm using https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson for the conversion. I'm using mocha for testing, I've looked into https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock and sinon for stubbing, but haven't gotten them to work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the lambda function upload the zipped JSON file to a server or something? If so, it sounds like you need to break that into smaller functions. That's a lot of tasks given to a single function, and you need a way to check each individual task.

Comment: it uploads the zipped json file to another s3 bucket. so there's a source bucket with all the csv files, and whenever a new csv file gets uploaded to that bucket, the lambda function gets triggered and uploads the zipped json file to another bucket